# Woocommerce - Disable Downloadable Product with other Product in single Order

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking to stop mixing different types of Product in cart/Order.

Use Case - Non virtual products that are downloadable should not go with any other Products in single cart/Order.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'remove_all_other_if_individual' );

    function remove_all_other_if_individual( $cart_item_data ) {

        global $woocommerce;
        $items                       = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        $is_downloadable_incart  = false;
        foreach ( $items as $item => $values ) {
            $_product                    = wc_get_product( $values[ 'data' ]->get_id() );
            if ( $_product->is_downloadable() )
                $is_downloadable_incart  = TRUE;
        }
        if ( $is_downloadable_incart )
            $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Do nothing with the data and return
        return true;
    }
```